# How can i update column name in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, sql-update

I am using DynamoDB for my backend database operations. One of my tables contains column name is 'Region'. When I am scanning this table, I applied a filter with Region. That time DynamoDB is throwing an error message. 'Region' is a keyword of DynamoDB.

How can I change column name Region to State?

Answer (score 2):

You don't really have to change the column name. You can do this using placeholders:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ExpressionPlaceholders.html